# Pip install local package invalidates docker cache in upper layers

Tags: docker, caching, pip, continuous-integration

I created a multistage docker file where in the base image I prepare anaconda environment with required packages and in the final image I copy the anaconda and install the local package.

I noticed that on every CI build and push  all of the layers are recomputed and pushed, including the one big anaconda layer.

Here is how I build it

```bash
DOCKER_BUILTKIT=1 docker build -t my_image:240beac6 \
-f docker/dockerfiles/Dockerfile . \
--build-arg BASE_IMAGE=base_image:240beac64 --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 \
--cache-from my_image:latest
docker push my_image:240beac6
```

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE as base

FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# enable conda
ENV PATH=/root/miniconda3/bin/:${PATH}

COPY --from=base /opt/fast_align/* /usr/bin/
COPY --from=base /usr/local/bin/yq /usr/local/bin/yq
COPY --from=base /root/miniconda3 /root/miniconda3

COPY . /opt/my_package
# RUN  pip  install --no-deps /opt/my_package
```

If I leave the last run command commented out, the docker only builds the last COPY (if some file in the context changed) layer.
However, if I try to install it, it invalidates everything.

Is it because, I change the `/root/miniconda3` with the pip install?
If so, I am surprised by that, I was hoping the lower RUN commands can't mess up the higher commands.

Is there a way to copy the conda environment from the base image, install the local image in a separate command and still benefit from the caching?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, albeit a bit hacky would be to replace the last `RUN` with `CMD` and install the package on start of the container. It would be almost instant as the requirements are already installed in the base image.